# why is eclipse formatting my xml file on save

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

When I save an XMl document, eclipse formats it (badly). I wish to turn it off. I have checked the preferences for shortcuts assigned to ctrl+s, the xml file prefs and more but I am unable to find where it is configured to do such a thing. Oh And I also have WTP and jboss tools installed if that's of any use.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to the type of editor that It was opening in. It was opening in a specific hibernate xml editor (I couldnt figure out how to change the save action of it), and so I changed to the standard XML editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have active "Save actions":

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions

Comment: Yes, but that's the only configuration in a regular Eclipse installation, where you can enable Save actions.

Comment: Do you have any other custom plugin installed (besides Jboss tools)?

Comment: The only additional plugin is mylyn

Comment: Which editor is used to edit XML files? Is it the default XML editor? You can check this with a right click, and then "Open with"

Comment: Hibernate 3.0 XML editor. That's probably why. Do you know how I change it's settings?